# get last value of td whose class is same using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery. I have a html code like :

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="price">price</td>
     <td class="total">10 Rs</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="price">Total:</td>
     <td class="total">100 Rs</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want only total price amount as **100 Rs**. So what code should I have to write to resolve this?

Comment: `$('.total:last').text()`

Comment: ^ as simple as that.

Comment: You can use eq for particular element $('.total:eq(1)').text(), http://jsbin.com/gusapolodu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>last demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">price</td>
    <td class="total">10 Rs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">Total:</td>
    <td class="total">100 Rs</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script>
  alert($( "tr td:last" ).text());
 </script>

</body>
```